# сравнить 2 списка в python

Tags: python

Привет всем,
Как узнать, какой элемент в списке неравен другому такому же элементу в другом списке? И если элементы неравны, найти позицию элементов, которые неравны

```
a = [u'120 devon 15.61', u'126 korn05000000000000 12.96', u'128 itswat 20.58',]
b = [u'120', u'devon', u'15.61', u'126', u'korn05', u'12.96', u'128', u'itswat', u'20.58']
if(u' '.join(b) == u' '.join(a)):
     pass
else:
     ?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [u'120 devon 15.61', u'126 korn05000000000000 12.96', u'128 itswat 20.58',]
b = [u'120', u'devon', u'15.61', u'126', u'korn05', u'12.96', u'128', u'itswat', u'20.58']
x = u' '.join(a)
y = u' '.join(b)
if(x == y):
    pass
else:
    a1 = x.split(' ')
    b1 = y.split(' ')
    for index, value in enumerate(a1):
        if (b1[index] != value):
            print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [u'120 devon 15.61', u'126 korn05000000000000 12.96', u'128 itswat        20.58',]
b = [u'120', u'devon', u'15.61', u'126', u'korn05', u'12.96', u'128',     u'itswat', u'20.58']
x = u' '.join(a).split()
y = u' '.join(b).split()
for index, value in enumerate(x):
    if (y[index] != value):
            print(index)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ' '.join(a).split()
b = ' '.join(b).split()
index_list = [a.index(x) for x, y in zip(a, b) if not x == y]
```

если длина списков разная

```
a = iter(' '.join(a).split())
b = iter(' '.join(b).split())
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    try:
        if not x == next(b):
            print(i)
    except StopIteration:  # len(a) > len(b)
        print(i)
try:
    while next(b):  # len(a) < len(b)
        i += 1
        print(i)
except StopIteration:pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти позиции, в которых элементы с одинаковыми индексами различаются в паре списков:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 20, 30]
indices_uniq = [i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a, b)) if x != y]
# -> [1, 2]
```

Результат `[1, 2]` так как второй и третий элементы отличаются. Выводятся только индексы `i < min(len(a), len(b))`, так как нет в более коротком списке элементов для соответствия (иначе, можно [`itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fill_value=sentinel)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) использовать вместо `zip(a,b)`).

Для буквального ввода в вопросе, результат `[0,1,2]`, то есть все элементы различаются попарно в заданных списках. Если хочется сравнить ввод как последовательность разделённых пробелом слов, то сперва необходимо нормализовать ввод (`get_words()`), а затем уже сравнивать соответствующие слова (`unequal_indicies(a, b)`):

```
def get_words(chunks):
    return (word for chunk in chunks for word in chunk.split())

def unequal_indices(a, b):
    return (i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(a, b)) if x != y)

a = ["120 devon 15.61", "126 korn05000000000000 12.96", "128 itswat 20.58"]
b = ["120", "devon", "15.61", "126", "korn05", "12.96", "128", "itswat", "20.58"]
print(list(unequal_indices(get_words(a), get_words(b))))
# -> [4]
```

В этом случае (при сравнении по словам) результат `[4]`, то есть отличаются только пятые слова в заданной паре текстов.

---

[В тестах](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), можно использовать `self.assertEqual(a, b)`, который покажет различия между списками (Python 3), если они есть:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./__main__.py", line 13, in test
    self.assertEqual(a, b)
AssertionError: Lists differ: [1, 2, 3, 4] != [1, 20, 30]

First differing element 1:
2
20

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 3:
4

- [1, 2, 3, 4]
?         ^^^

+ [1, 20, 30]
?      +   ^
```

---

Для сравнения последовательностей, содержащих текст, [можно `difflib` попробовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html):

```
>>> print(*difflib.ndiff(a, b), sep='\n')
- 120 devon 15.61
- 126 korn05000000000000 12.96
- 128 itswat 20.58
+ 120
+ devon
+ 15.61
+ 126
+ korn05
+ 12.96
+ 128
+ itswat
+ 20.58
```

Вывод показывает, что все элементы отличаются.

Если нормализовать ввод, то ожидаемо только одно слово отличается:

```
>>> print(*difflib.ndiff(list(get_words(a)), list(get_words(b))), sep='\n')
  120
  devon
  15.61
  126
- korn05000000000000
+ korn05
  12.96
  128
  itswat
  20.58
```